# Почему выражение всегда = true?

Tags: java, while, equals

У меня возникла проблема. Мой цикл while должен выполнятся до тех пор, пока я не введу либо C, либо F. Но на самом деле он выполняется всегда.

```java
String inputType = "";
while (!inputType.equals("C") || !inputType.equals("F")) {
    System.out.println("Введите C, если хотите ввести строку из консоли, или F, если хотите ввести строку из файла");
    inputType = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Что можно с этим сделать? И почему это работает не так, как я ожидаю?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ очевиден. Либо не равно С, либо не равно F. Предположим, вы ввели C. Тогда эта строка не равна F, и цикл пойдет дальше.
Замените "или" на "и", и все заработает.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String inputType = "";
while (!inputType.equals("C") && !inputType.equals("F")) {
    System.out.println("Введите C, если хотите ввести строку из консоли, или F, если хотите ввести строку из файла");
    inputType = scan.nextLine();
}
```